# Drawer navigator is retaining state post logout. How to clear it's state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

I have a Main screen which comes after login. There is a drawer Navigator which contains a Second Screen and Logout. When I go to the Second screen and then open drawer navigator and click on logout then after I login again, the Second screen is opened instead of the main screen. I want the Main Screen to open even though I logout from the second screen. How is this possible?

Actual Flow -> Login -> MainScreen -> DrawerNavigator -> SecondScreen ->DrawerNavigator-> Logout -> Login -> SecondScreen

Expected flow -> Login -> MainScreen -> DrawerNavigator -> SecondScreen ->DrawerNavigator-> Logout -> Login -> HomeScreen

How should I get Expected Flow?

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're using React Navigation. You'll want to follow the guidance at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow - doing it this way should fix your issue so you'll always land on the home screen when logged in.